# KineticJS: drag a group from toolbar to stage

Tags: drag-and-drop, kineticjs

I already implemented a solution using KineticJS of drag and drop of items: from a toolbar (or an accordion, it doesn't matter) to a white area, a stage or canvas, the items are images and rectangles. The rectangles represent a room and the images are the equipments.

In all the examples I found after googling (until now) are basically about drawing a `Kinetic.Group` inside of a layer, adding shapes to that group and make it draggable in the stage.

The problem here is that I don't know how to make a rectangle to be a group, so that when I drag it over the canvas, the images will be dragged as well; ie when I drag a room that contains items, the whole group is dragged and dropped. I want to implement something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/tbYLe/2/ which performs as described above.

**EDIT :** this is what I have done until now http://jsfiddle.net/wQ8YA/15/

Comment: Can you please provide the jsfiddle link of the final answer that you wanted to achieve if it's not too much trouble??

Comment: In the end, I gave up on the DOM element and implemented the solution with pure KineticJS + Javascript (it was a reaaally bad idea). I'll try to find the jsfiddle of the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you should provide code you tried, that would help others help you.

The thing you are trying to do is create a group, which is between a layer and a shape, so you add shapes to the group and then you can drag the entire group.

The attributes a group can have are listed here: http://kineticjs.com/docs/Kinetic.Group.html

And here is an example of a group: http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/kineticjs/html5-canvas-drag-and-drop-a-group-with-kineticjs/

notice that there is no color or shape, but it can be thought of as a rectangle, much like a layer is a rectangle, and the canvas is a rectangle.  **A group is just a container, not a shape**

So if you want a "room," I advise this approach.

```
function createGroup(width,height){
//create a group - define a size for it 
var group = new Kinetic.Group({
    draggable: true //make group draggable
});
//create a rectangle
//add rectangle to group - fill up entire group - this will be the visual representation for your group - this rectangle should not be draggable
//return group
}

// use of
var myRoom = createGroup(100, 200);
myRoom.add(new Kinetic.Circle({config})); // this new circle can be draggable
```

Comment: @Sahar, let me know if you need any more help on this

Comment: I worked on this issue like you explained, I created the group (with same dimensions of the container so that everything would be dragged together), added it to the layer, and wrote this line after each drag of an image `group.add(image)` but still nothing happens :( it's becoming more complex to me..

Comment: after looking at your code, you are using jquery droppable/draggable to insert items into the container, rather than doing the cloning/dragging/dropping with kineticjs and javascript. What you need to do is rewrite this so that when you drag items from one area to another they get cloned. Sorry, but this should be a kineticjs only implementation. You can make a canvas, add a left panel for your options, then allow dragging on the options, listen for dropping into the right panel and do your logic from there.

Comment: I think the problem right now is that jquery is adding the items into a canvas container, rather than kineticjs handling this. Your other option is to write some logic and have jquery handle nesting items into a hierarchy so that your items move as a group.

Comment: Oh I thought I was doing it with kineticJS.. I see, So what if I change the technology? I can't do it with pure jquery?

Comment: Sure you can, you just have to flush out the logic and write the code. Each time you put something in the right container and it is a rectangle, it too has to become a drop target.

Comment: Great :) I should try to adapt this to my solution now. Thanks a lot @EliteOctagon !

Comment: The user is free to drag the items one by one after they are drawn, so do I have to create a new group for each new item that I drag inside the big group (myRoom), and put the item in that group, to position them all?

Comment: You can, but I only recommend creating a new group each time you create a new room, then once you have a room, then it has a group associated with it rather than creating a new group for each item. I don't know the structure of the application entirely, but you're dealing with a hierarchical structure here and you need to write the logic so that the hierarchy is respected. Something like your onDrop function which checks if the item dropped is an item or a new room, if an item, drop in corresponding room, else, create new room.

Comment: @EliteOctagon Could you please take a look at this?? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25112205/make-objects-inside-container-move-with-container